# Can I create a custom android OS?

Tags: spotify, galaxy, samsung

I currently have an old Galaxy Trend Lite GT S7390 that is so old it's virtually unusable. I want to give it the funtionality of an old mp3 player, but since it has wifi functionality, I thought it would be cool to have an OS that would allow it to work with the Spotify app, however that's ALL I want it to do. I just want it to work with Spotify.

Is this possible? I'm perfectly fine figuring out how to do it, I just need to know if it's technically possible and a direction to begin at.

I haven't tried much yet.

Answer (score 1):

Android is open source. You can modify it how ever you want. You can flash it to any device (support withstanding). But will it support your all your device's specific cheap Chinese hardware? Likely not. You'll probably have to write modules to integrate your specific hardware drivers. That' why most Android phone makers give their own version of Android. However, they have to pay licensing to Google because they are charging you for it. As long as you don't charge for your resulting product, you do not have pay licensing.

Android is written in Java. Here's a link to the project:

https://source.android.com/

I hope your computer can handle running Android Studio. It's a hungry, hungry resource monster.

[image]